# Spider found in bathroom can’t identify

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image]

Found this spider in my bathroom on the wall by the door. Near Houston, TX.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly a spider belonging to the genus Scytodes. It largely resembles the species *[S. thoracica](https://animaldiversity.org/accounts/Scytodes_thoracica/)* with very similar markings to the picture above. It is a common spider in the United States, and is often found in houses.

[image]

Comment: Hi@ShroomZed and welcome to Bio.SE. Thanks for providing an answer to this question! However, if you check out our [guide for writing good answers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), you'll see that we really are seeking answers that *provide, cite, or link-to support for their answers. In this way, we cut down on misinformation while simultaneously providing easy access for further learning for the OP.  Please consider adding [reputable] support for your [seemingly valid] answer, and you'll almost certainly receive more positive attention (i.e., up votes). Thanks!